# HTTPWebRequest Body Formatting

Tags: c#, http, httpwebrequest

This is a stupidly trivial question, but I can't seem to find a proper example anywhere with more than one property being set. Basically, I'm trying to send a POST request with C#'s HTTPWebRequest library while specifying two different fields in the body of the request.

So far, I have this:

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
request.Method = "POST";
ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
byte[] byt = encoding.GetBytes("recipient=12345ABC");
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = byt.Length;
Stream newStream = request.GetRequestStream();
newStream.Write(byt, 0, byt.Length);
```

Followed by the usual GetResponse() stuff. This works fine, everything's dandy, but I can't figure out how to specify multiple body elements, such as both of these:

```
recipient=12345ABC
body="testmessage"
```

I've tried separating them with a semicolon, an ampersand, and a comma, but the server keeps returning Error 400: Bad Request. Perhaps I'm just misunderstanding how this process works?

Comment: You should be able to separate them with an ampersand ("&") just as you would for a GET request in a query string (e.g. `recipient=12345ABC&body=testmessage`). You may have to URLEncode your `body` if it contains special characters.

Comment: It's still giving me a bad request response, unfortunately. I've also tried moving the parameters from the body directly to the URL itself and appending it, but it still doesn't like it. One thing to note is that they specify the "recipients" parameter and a "text" parameter; in the example URL they give, they don't actually say "text=blah" - they just append "&blah" after "recipients=12345ABC". Is this some kind of shortcut, or is this indicative of something I'm missing? (Edit: By "they" I'm referring to the API writers)

Comment: ^ Another thing to add, the JSON example they give uses "body=blah" as opposed to "text=blah" even though the parameter name they supply is "text."

Comment: POST data needs to be in key/value pairs, as that's the format expected by the "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" content type. If there's no "text" key in the POST data, then the request is indeed "bad."

Comment: Ugh, yeah, their examples were wrong. Turns out the actual parameters are "recipients" and "text" as opposed to "recipients" and "body" - gotta love sloppy APIs. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API docs were sloppily done. Actual parameter names were "recipients" and "text" - code worked fine after this change.

URL encoding in the body works fine, "recipients=12345ABC&text=This+is+URL+escaped+text" worked like a charm in either the URL itself or the POST body.